# A stop job is running for WPA supplicant - slow to shut down

Tags: network-manager, shutdown

Been running Ubuntu 17.10 for a while. All was fine till the other day when I did a `sudo apt update` and `upgrade`.

Now it takes 9.5 minutes for it to shut down..

I press <kbd>esc</kbd> on shut down and it shows:

```
A stop job is running for WPA supplicant
A stop job is running for Raise network interfaces 
A stop job is running for Network Manager
```

These keep repeating until it finally shuts down 9.5 minutes or more later.

Any help would be much appreciated
I have tried numerous things...

Comment: Please detail those things you tried, otherwise we will probably suggest them again...

Comment: I just hit esc on shut down and got this                                                                                A stop job is running for WPA supplicant                                                                          A stop job is running for Raise network interfaces                                                        A stop job is running for Network Manager                                                                          And those just keep repeating till it finally shuts down 9.5 minutes or more later.

Comment: same issue here, but if I wait for more time, it got fixed after 30m

Comment: Possible duplicate of [kworker blocked for more than 120 seconds Ubuntu 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/965856/kworker-blocked-for-more-than-120-seconds-ubuntu-17-10)

Comment: Same problem running `shutdown -h now` from a command line. It prints `A stop job is running for Network Manager WPA supplicant` and it doesn't stop, at least not in the first 5 minutes. It seems related to this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1724317