# 17.10 system takes a very long time to turn off

Tags: shutdown, 17.10

My operating system is Ubuntu 17.10. When I shut down my laptop, it takes about half an hour or more to turn off. What's the problem? With Ubuntu 17.04 this was not the case.

Comment: What do your logs say?

Comment: Try `sudo poweroff` and see if it goes down in a timely manner...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 16.04 hangs on shutdown/restart](https://askubuntu.com/questions/764568/ubuntu-16-04-hangs-on-shutdown-restart)

Comment: You could switch to a terminal with `CTRL+ATL+F1`, login and then type `shutdown -h now`. The messages there should give you more hints. Feel free to post them in the post, so we can investigate further.

Comment: What method do you use to turn off the laptop? What laptop is it (manufacturer and full model number)?

Comment: I think this is version specific. Maybe related to [Kworker blocked for more than 120 seconds](https://askubuntu.com/questions/965856/kworker-blocked-for-more-than-120-seconds-ubuntu-17-10)

Comment: @pbhj         Using the graphical interface and commands / acer - Aspire F 15-F5-573G-77ZP

Comment: Try ctrl-alt-f1 to switch to a console, run `top` and see if there's anything at the top of the list that looks unfamiliar, note that down, don't close top yet. Ctrl-alt-f7 will switch you back to your GUI session, do your usual routine for shutdown, do ctrl-alt-f1 again, see what is in the list that wasn't there before or that is higher up than before. You could also try `sudo shutdown -h now` from the console, or `sudo poweroff`. Is that faster, do any errors get reported? Whilst shutting down you can `tail -f /var/log/syslog`which may give some clues.