# Ubuntu 17.10 not shutting down properly

Tags: shutdown, 17.10

Ubuntu 17.10 works great with my Acer laptop, but when I shut it down via CLI or GUI it will not shutdown for a long time (hours) and I have to press power button and shut it down forcefully.

I have Nvidia GeForce 940 Mx graphics card, if it's relevant.

Comment: You should see the real error message: press the `ESC` button during the shutdown and see what it's written there.

Comment: How exactly are you trying to shut the system down? Did you try `sudo shutdown`? What's its output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [kworker blocked for more than 120 seconds Ubuntu 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/965856/kworker-blocked-for-more-than-120-seconds-ubuntu-17-10)

Answer (score 0):

Installing Nvidia driver helped me. From command prompt:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-384
```

or you can use :

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```