# Ubuntu 17.10+ disable netplan

Tags: grub2, netplan

According to: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Netplan

I can disable netplan by: "preseeding netcfg/do_not_use_netplan=true (adding it the the command-line when you boot the Ubuntu Server installation media"

I'm assuming this is done via `/etc/default/grub` but where exactly do I add "netcfg/do_not_use_netplan=true"?

Is it added to: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX

I currently have this set to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="ipv6.disable=1"
```

What would be the syntax to add in "netcfg/do_not_use_netplan=true" to this existing setting?

P.S. YES, I want to remove netplan, so the question is specifically about how to do that, not why.

Comment: I did a simpler and verified procedure without reboots and crossed fingers. Please, check it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The exact method to do this is hard, perhaps impossible to locate now in the early days of netplan.

> I currently have this set to:
>
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="ipv6.disable=1"

I assume that you mean that your `/etc/default/grub` reads, in part:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="ipv6.disable=1"
<snip>
```

I also assume that the link you give suggests that you add the referenced wording:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="ipv6.disable=1 netcfg/do_not_use_netplan=true"
<snip>
```

I suggest that you do just that, followed by:

```
sudo update-grub
```

You will also need:

```
sudo apt install ifupdown
```

It may already be installed.

Finally, fill in `/etc/network/interfaces` manually to configure your network the way you want it.

The exact process to do this post-installation, as far as Google and I can find, doesn't exist. Reboot with your fingers crossed!

Comment: Answer from @chili555 was not enough for me. I had to remove every yaml file from netplan directories ( {/run , /lib, /etc }/netplan/*.yaml ). Then, reboot and the network should works back with /etc/network/interfaces (guess this is a normal fallback).

Answer (score 13):

**These directions have been tested also to Ubuntu 18.04.1 and will very likely work also for any future release using `netplan` and `systemd`.**

There's no need at all to fiddle with GRUB nor any manual file removal.
The configuration set up in `/etc/networking` files and directories **will survive reboots**.

These are the **verified** steps:

1. Check the actual interface names you are interested in with `ip l` for the *links* (aka interfaces) and with `ip a` for addresses.
2. Install `ifupdown` with `sudo apt -y install ifupdown`.
3. Purge `netplan` with `sudo apt -y purge netplan.io`.
4. Configure `/etc/network/interfaces` and/or `/etc/network/interfaces.d` accordingly to your needs (`man 5 interfaces` can be of some help with examples).
5. Restart the `networking` service with `sudo systemctl restart networking; systemctl status networking` or `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart; /etc/init.d/networking status`. The output of the `status` command should mention `active` as its status.
6. The command `ip a` will show whether the expected network configuration has been applied.
7. Optionally, manually purge the remants of the netplan configuration files with `sudo rm -vfr /usr/share/netplan /etc/netplan`.

No reboot is needed in order to "refresh" the IP configuration: it will be active as of step no.5 . In case of troubles, double check the interface names. A typical IPv4 DHCP configuration will resemble this one:

```
auto enp0s3
iface enp0s3 inet dhcp
```

while a static IPv4 address can be configured like this:

```
auto enp0s3
iface enp0s3 inet static
address 192.168.255.42/24
gateway 192.168.255.254
#dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 208.67.222.222
```

Beware, the `dns-nameservers` entry won't work (thanks @Velkan for pointing it out!): the resolver is still using `/etc/resolv.conf` and `systemd` is providing his own resolution service from `127.0.0.53`.
So you can manually update it (no networking restart needed!):

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 208.67.222.222
```

But his would be only a temporary solution to vanish after the next reboot.

To get a permanent solution you need to edit `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` and add a line like this one to the "`[Resolve]`" stanza:

```
DNS=8.8.8.8 208.67.222.222
```

Please, refer to `man 5 resolved.conf` for the full documentation.

Finally, in the unlikely case any network service is not responding as expected, then that services may need a restart. But that's a weird non-standard network daemon behavior.

Comment: Did this survive a reboot? A similar procedure worked for me but upon reboot I find that netplan has taken over again

Comment: Yes, indeed! I will re-check everything, though.

Comment: It works after reboot.

Comment: Step 7 is a bit wrong. Some remaining files (as you call them) could have been installed by other packages than netplan. Removing them is totally useless and could lead to issues if in future, you want to switch back to netplan.

Comment: It isn't wrong. Stuff installed under /usr/share/netplan and /etc/netplan belong to netplan as well as those directories themselves. Unless you have evidence for something else.

Comment: @Uqbar You're wrong. As for the init system where several packages can install systemd unit files, sysvinit scripts and upstart jobs while some of those are not being used, you can have several packages installing netplan conffiles. Those conffiles don't belong to the netplan.io package directly. If in future you want switch back to netplan, you could have issues due to missing conffiles. The reinstallation of the missing conffiles will involve the reinstallation of the packages that provided them, using the --force-confmiss DPKG(1) option. Most of beginners will not figure out easily ;)

Comment: The `dns-nameservers` doesn't work though. option is kind of ignored. Between `systemd-resolved` and `systemd-networkd` I don't know where it's lost.

Comment: @Velkan /etc/resolv.conf is still effectively ruling and being overwritten by systemd at every reboot. I updated the solution. I think the situation with ifup, netplan and systemd is getting really crazy! ;-)

Comment: +1. if you add to grub `net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0` the interface names will be good old `ethX` [source](https://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/mini-howtos/change-default-network-name-ens33-to-old-eth0-on-ubuntu-16-04.html)

Comment: I don't fiddle with grub unless necessary. Udev can accomplish the same.

Comment: Ruinning 3 sudo apt -y purge netplan.io will also uninstall "ubuntu-minimal" which is kind of a bad idea, no? If dependencies evolve you may miss one...

Comment: No, it's not a worse idea than disabling netplan. If you accept to deviate by removing netplan, then removing (just) a container like ubuntu-minimal is not a bad idea. It's your will.

Answer (score 2):

Had this issue on Ubuntu 18.10 Server 64-bits (running on Virtual Box) and the following steps allowed to remove netplan and install Network Manager - not sure if they work for ifupdown. These steps are adapted from @Uqbar's answer (thank you).

1. Check the actual interface names you are interested in with `ip l` for the links (aka interfaces) and with `ip a` for addresses.
2. Install **Network Manager** with sudo `apt -y install network-manager`.
3. Purge **netplan** with `sudo apt -y purge netplan.io`.
4. Optionally, manually purge the remnants of netplan's configuration files with `sudo rm -vfr /usr/share/netplan /etc/netplan`.
5. Configure `/etc/network/interfaces` accordingly to your needs (`man 5 interfaces` can be of some help with examples). Mine is configured as follows:

   ```
   auto lo
   iface lo inet loopback

   auto enp0s3
   allow-hotplug enp0s3
   iface enp0s3 inet dhcp
   ```
6. On file `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`, modify the line `managed=false` to `managed=true`. This will make Network Manager manage the interfaces configured in `/etc/network/interfaces`.
7. Restart the Network Manager service with `sudo service network-manager restart`. The output of the status command should mention **active** as its status.
8. The command `nmcli dev` will show whether the expected network configuration has been applied. Initially interface `enp0s3` (my virtual ethernet) was appearing as unmanaged. After rebooting the machine, it appeared as connected. An example output of `nmcli` follows:

   ```
   DEVICE           TYPE      STATE         CONNECTION
   enp0s3           ethernet  connected     Ifupdown (enp0s3)
   wlxc46e1f179799  wifi      disconnected  --
   lo               loopback  unmanaged     --
   ```

---

<s>**NOTE:** I'm having some issues with processes hanging, as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/965856/kworker-blocked-for-more-than-120-seconds-ubuntu-17-10) and [here](https://www.blackmoreops.com/2014/09/22/linux-kernel-panic-issue-fix-hung_task_timeout_secs-blocked-120-seconds-problem/). I managed to change the `vm.dirty_ratio` and `vm.dirty_background_ratio to 10 and 5 respectively, from the defaults 20 and 10. For that, execute the following commands:</s>

```
sudo sysctl -w vm.dirty_ratio=10
sudo sysctl -w vm.dirty_background_ratio=5
```

I'll update this answer reporting the results after running the VM for some time.

It's been a long time, but I think this problem never occurred again (can't verify as the VM is corrupted). Never really understood why; I'll leave the note here for future reference. See also my comment bellow.

Comment: How is the NOTE related to netplan etc? Seems to be a completely unrelated issue...

Comment: I can't remember the exact details, but, if I remember correctly, I was loosing connection via SSH with Ubuntu. The links above report some issues with network connection and suggest change the values of the  mentioned parameters. Thus the note.

Comment: Works for me.  Especially take note of Step 6 above "modify the line managed=false to managed=true" which doesn't seem to be mentioned elsewhere.  Also note that if you're using WiFi (e.g. a laptop) its configuration information is in the /etc/NetworkManager hierarchy and there are no Wlan entries in /etc/network/interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

**Here is MY answer on how to DISABLE Netplan without uninstalling it (tested for Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS Server and Desktop):**

The solution is based on my own investigations. I do not know, if this is an official way to do it, though it is pretty much systemd like.

Netplan is executed during system boot by a systemd generator file `netplan` inisde `/usr/lib/systemd/system-generators/`. This is a symlink pointing to `/usr/lib/netplan/generate`. So you just have to remove it, to keep Netplan from beeing executed at boot:

**DISABLE Netplan:**

```
sudo rm /usr/lib/systemd/system-generators/netplan
```

Reboot your system and you will not have any configurations generated by Netplan available inside `/run/...` anymore.

Stop Netplan from running while system is up:

```
sudo chmod a-x /usr/sbin/netplan
```

**ENABLE Netplan:**

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/netplan/generate /usr/lib/systemd/system-generators/netplan
```

Reboot your system and Netplan will be executed during system boot and will generate back-end configurations inside `/run/...` again, if yaml-files are present in one of the Netplan configuration directories.

Make Netplan executable again, while system is running:

```
sudo chmod a+x /usr/sbin/netplan
```

**This is all you need to do!** There is no need for adding/removing `netcfg/do_not_use_netplan=True` to your `/etc/default/grub` in addition to the two commands above.

**Background:**

So far I could not find anything usefull that is done by `netcfg/do_not_use_netplan=True`. I don't and can't say that it might not do something, but I could not reproduce, that it would do something (I would expect it to do).

I can for sure say, that it does NOT stop Netplan from beeing executed at boot time. Without disabling Netplan like described above, add `debug` to your `/etc/default/grub` so that it looks like follows,

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="netcfg/do_not_use_netplan=True debug"
```

to verify yourself.

After system boot execute

```
dmesg | grep netplan
```

and you will get something like the following:

```
[    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-74-generic root=UUID=74a27c05-a0a8-4a7c-a757-5edda35a5933 ro debug netcfg/do_not_use_netplan=True debian-installer/language=de keyboard-configuration/layoutcode?=de
[    0.037275] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-74-generic root=UUID=74a27c05-a0a8-4a7c-a757-5edda35a5933 ro debug netcfg/do_not_use_netplan=True debian-installer/language=de keyboard-configuration/layoutcode?=de
[    3.086458] systemd[346]: /usr/lib/systemd/system-generators/netplan succeeded.
[    3.397282] systemd[1]: unit_file_build_name_map: normal unit file: /run/systemd/system/netplan-ovs-cleanup.service
```

Like you can see, the command line is read correctly, but Netplan is still executed.

So I thought it because it reads "do_not_use_netplan" it would may still execute Netplan, but would not use the back-end configuration, once a valid configuration with **ifupdown** `/etc/network/interfaces` does exist.

But NO, even if **ifupdown** is installed and a valid configuration is placed inside `/etc/network/interfaces` Netplan does still generate back-end configurations and applies them and configurations from ifupdown are still ignored.

Only if I do disable Netplan like described at the beginning, the ifupdown configuration will be used and will start working like expected.

Answer (score -1):

As an addition to this answer, the approach does work (18.04.4 LTS) for a move back to ifup/down, and is much easier that some other proposals.  I did reboot, but am not sure it was needed.

Steps:

**`ip a`** (to get the valid device names and IP addresses if required)

**`apt install ifupdown`**

**`vi /etc/network/interfaces`**  # if you are doing this, you know what to put in

**`vi /etc/resolv.conf`**  # if you are doing this, you know what to put in

**`apt purge netplan.io`**

**`init 6`** # not sure if this was needed

Redundant files may still be present, but I have decided not to look for them