# After upgrade to 18.04 Openvpn doesnt work anymore

Tags: openvpn

I cannot establish a connection to the openvpn server anymore.

```
grep VPN /var/sys/log
```

Gives me this output:

```
Starting OpenVPN connection to server...    
Failed to start OpenVPN connection to server.
Stopped OpenVPN connection to server.
```

The openvpn log in `/var/log/openvpn.log`
doesnt seem to exist.

EDIT: I'm guessing I messed the server config up somehow? I get these logs from:

```
grep ovpn /var/sys/log
May 16 03:06:50 xxx ovpn-server[23659]: Options error: --dh fails with 'dh2048.pem': No such file or directory (errno=2)
May 16 03:06:45 xxx ovpn-server[23654]: Options error: --cert fails with 'server.crt': No such file or directory (errno=2)
May 16 03:06:50 xxx ovpn-server[23659]: WARNING: cannot stat file 'server.key': No such file or directory (errno=2)
May 16 03:06:50 xxx ovpn-server[23659]: Options error: --key fails with 'server.key': No such file or directory (errno=2)
May 16 03:06:50 xxx ovpn-server[23659]: Options error: Please correct these errors.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Permission chmod issues maybe?

When I upgraded to 18.04, my vpn client stopped working but I just installed network-manager-openvpn and network-manager-openvpn-gnome via terminal and it allows me to just pick openvpn config files and it connects from there.

Maybe this will be a possible workaround for you if it is not permissions related.

EDIT:
I looked up what you said and came to the openvpn forums with an apparent work around.
https://forums.openvpn.net/viewtopic.php?t=23979

Comment: I tried this and I can set the configs in the gnome terminal but my certificates use an outdated encryption algorithm :(. Hoping for an answer and a quick fix now. Thanks though!

Comment: I've updated my answer with information from the openvpn forums. Please have a look there.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently my user certificates wont load because they are secured by md5 and openssl considers these too weak.

Logs:

Any suggestions? Downgrade to a different OpenSSL version?

```
Wed May 16 14:05:49 2018 OpenSSL: error:140AB18E:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_certificate:ca md too weak
```

Answer (score 1):

My issue was that 18.04 introduced netplan and netplan/networkmanager agree to not manage each others interfaces.  Until the latest upgrade, my configurations had been in place, but something had gotten overwritten.

I ended up removing the configuration from netplan and update the networkmanager config to name all the interfaces.

I also found the instructions for not using netplan below.

[Ubuntu 17.10 disable netplan](https://askubuntu.com/questions/977243/ubuntu-17-10-disable-netplan)

```
sudo apt install ifupdown
sudo apt purge netplan
```

My /etc/network/interfaces looks like this:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

I also had changed the name of my Broadcom NetXtreme Gigabit network card as it was non-standard from the old name to eth0

`/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<<your macid here>>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", NAME="eth0"
```

instructions

```
sudo service restart networking
sudo service restart network-manager
```

Comment: Feedback on the downvote would be helpful so I can improve in future.