# Disable netplan in install iso

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation, iso, netplan

**This is not a discussion about netplan, I just want to craft an iso that has netplan disabled.**

The FAQ (https://netplan.io/faq#how-to-go-back-to-ifupdown) says "[...]This is done by adding the preseed line to the command line when booting the installation media[...]"

I repacked the current Ubuntu 18.04.1 server image and changed the `boot/grub/grub.cfg` to not use netplan. But for some reason that is not working.

```
menuentry "Install Ubuntu Server" {
        set gfxpayload=keep
        linux   /install/vmlinuz  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu-server.seed quiet netcfg/do_not_use_netplan=true ---
        initrd  /install/initrd.gz
}
```

Can someone tell what I did wrong? How to get this to work?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/977243/416190