# Reboot or shutdown hangs at "Reached target Reboot". task kworker/2:2:214 blocked for more than 120 seconds

Tags: nvidia, kernel, displayport, usb-c

This suddenly started happening today on my Lenovo [Thinkpad X1 Extreme Gen 2](https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/mobiles_pdf/p1_gen2_x1extreme_hmm_v1.pdf). The system configuration has not changed from when this issue did not occur.

I'm using NVIDIA's proprietary driver 440.82+really.440.64-0ubuntu6 to drive a Philips 276E8V plugged in via a USBC-DP cable, and a Dell WD15 dock with USB devices and headphones attached.

This issue does not occur if the display is never plugged in, but occurs if the display is unplugged before I press 'reboot'.

Distro & kernel: Kubuntu 20.04 LTS, kernel 5.4.0-31-generic

Specs: i7-9850H, GTX1650 Max-Q, 16GB DDR4-2666, HP EX920 NVMe SSD

```
May 26 16:06:09 jordan-ThinkPad kernel: INFO: task kworker/11:1:209 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
May 26 16:06:09 jordan-ThinkPad kernel:       Tainted: P           O      5.4.0-31-generic #35-Ubuntu
May 26 16:06:09 jordan-ThinkPad kernel: "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
May 26 16:06:09 jordan-ThinkPad kernel: kworker/11:1    D    0   209      2 0x80004000
May 26 16:06:09 jordan-ThinkPad kernel: Workqueue: events dp_altmode_work [typec_displayport]
May 26 16:06:09 jordan-ThinkPad kernel: Call Trace:
May 26 16:06:09 jordan-ThinkPad kernel:  __schedule+0x2e3/0x740
May 26 16:06:09 jordan-ThinkPad kernel:  schedule+0x42/0xb0
May 26 16:06:09 jordan-ThinkPad kernel:  schedule_preempt_disabled+0xe/0x10
May 26 16:06:09 jordan-ThinkPad kernel:  __mutex_lock.isra.0+0x182/0x4f0
May 26 16:06:09 jordan-ThinkPad kernel:  ? __switch_to_asm+0x34/0x70
May 26 16:06:09 jordan-ThinkPad kernel:  ? __switch_to_asm+0x34/0x70
May 26 16:06:09 jordan-ThinkPad kernel:  ? __switch_to_asm+0x40/0x70
May 26 16:06:09 jordan-ThinkPad kernel:  ? __switch_to_asm+0x40/0x70
May 26 16:06:09 jordan-ThinkPad kernel:  __mutex_lock_slowpath+0x13/0x20
May 26 16:06:09 jordan-ThinkPad kernel:  mutex_lock+0x2e/0x40
May 26 16:06:09 jordan-ThinkPad kernel:  ucsi_send_command+0x2a/0x60 [typec_ucsi]
May 26 16:06:09 jordan-ThinkPad kernel:  ucsi_displayport_enter+0x90/0x180 [typec_ucsi]
May 26 16:06:09 jordan-ThinkPad kernel:  typec_altmode_enter+0x4f/0x60 [typec]
May 26 16:06:09 jordan-ThinkPad kernel:  dp_altmode_work+0xde/0xf0 [typec_displayport]
May 26 16:06:09 jordan-ThinkPad kernel:  process_one_work+0x1eb/0x3b0
May 26 16:06:09 jordan-ThinkPad kernel:  worker_thread+0x4d/0x400
May 26 16:06:09 jordan-ThinkPad kernel:  kthread+0x104/0x140
May 26 16:06:09 jordan-ThinkPad kernel:  ? process_one_work+0x3b0/0x3b0
May 26 16:06:09 jordan-ThinkPad kernel:  ? kthread_park+0x90/0x90
May 26 16:06:09 jordan-ThinkPad kernel:  ret_from_fork+0x1f/0x40
```

Comment: It is stated in the logs that you can run this " echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs " to disable this message . Have you run this ?

Comment: See [this](https://www.blackmoreops.com/2014/09/22/linux-kernel-panic-issue-fix-hung_task_timeout_secs-blocked-120-seconds-problem/) . In the section " Solution for hung_task_timeout_secs " it's well explained.

Comment: @K7AAY I updated the post with distro and kernel

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/965856/kworker-blocked-for-more-than-120-seconds-ubuntu-17-10